# PHP session not set in some files

Tags: php, session

I have some trouble with PHP Sessions.
I was searching too much for answers, most had problems at `sesson_start()` function, that is not the case here I guess.

Index.php, Loginback.php, UserInfo.php all start with:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

There is index.php where I have login form with action loginback.php:

```
<form action="loginback.php"  method="POST" id="LoginForm">
    <input type="text" name="UserName" placeholder="Username" class="form-control"/>
    <input type="password" name="Password"  placeholder="Password"  class="form-control"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-info, OASButton" />
</form>
```

at LoginBack.php is validation for user input, if everything is OK I say:

```
$_SESSION["user"] = "Temo"; //string is for testingpurposes 
header("location: http://website.com/mine/index.php");
```

after redirecting at index.php If session is set I include "statistics.php" and it works just fine, if session is not set I incldue "logreg.php"- also works fine, but when I go to userinfo.php and check for session isset it always says no:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php  
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])==true){ 
       echo "Logged In!";
 } else {    
   echo "Not Logged in";} ?>
```

So bottom line, session is recognized at index.php but not recognized at userid.php. Any help?

`//sorry for my english.`

'K , I have no idea what happened, I have not touched those files but now I am logged in but can't log out, here is logoutback.php where it should happen:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php 
session_unset(); 
session_destroy();

header("location: http://website.om/mine/index.php"); ?>
```

Comment: on `LoginBack.php` also you need to add `session_start();`

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])==true)` is invalid syntax; that needs to be broken up into two separate conditions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {//code here } it works on index.php doesn't work on userinfo.php, so I don't think that is the case

Comment: @AlivetoDie I'm curious to see why your answer was downvoted. (and now deleted). And why the (still shown) answer got an upvote. Yours was correct.

Comment: @fred-ii can you explain what you mean ? I'm confused that same code works at one page and doesn't on another.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  actually some-one down-voted me without giving any reason,and also OP's comment is that my answer didn't worked for me.That's why i deleted it myself. Stack have to take some action regarding this type of down-vote.

Comment: I'm going with cookies until I have answer to the question. So far thank you for your help guys. Waiting for more feedback. Especially from you @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer,
for going to userinfo.php I had:
`<a href="http://www.website.com/mine/userinfo.php">`

and that was the problem,

> without www it works fine.

but also what was strange:  I created folder SESSION just with session stuff and when I was starting session from there and redirecting through the same url, it was working.
So anyways I't is finally over :)